# Add Multiple Records Using Linq to Entity?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an application where I am using linq to entity Now i want to store Multiple records in single query.

I want to hit db in minimum number.

Second Please suggest if there any option to insert multiple unique records in one query.

Thanks

**First Edit**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            keywordlist k = new keywordlist();
            k.Keyword = i.ToString();
            k.Status = true;
            DbFlb.AddObject("keywordlists", k);
        }
DbFlb.SaveChanges();
```

But this code db multiple times i need query that hit only one time.

Comment: show the code you've written so far.

Comment: I don't think you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796150/how-to-mass-insert-update-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: What SQL are you expecting to run? Your everyday INSERT statement in SQL only inserts one record at a time, so EF is going to do the same thing. The only way I can think of to do multiple inserts in SQL in the first place (outside of a bulk insert from a file) is to do something ugly like `INSERT TBL SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3`.

Comment: INSERTs can insert as many rows as you want: values (1), (2), (3), ...

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [SQL Server Bulk Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130809.aspx) operation, [Here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader) you can download a converter class that transforms the entity collection into an IDataReader.

[Christophe Geers has a good explanation on this](http://cgeers.com/2011/05/19/entity-framework-bulk-copy/)